# Android: onCreateOptionsMenu in one fragment inflates it's menu in all other fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

To begin with, I have a fragment-based app.
On the first fragment user sees `recyclerview` and I'm calling `onCreateOptionsMenu()` which makes menu with a `searchview`.
The problem is, when I switch to other fragments I also see this menu. And if  another fragment has its own menu, `inflater` adds items from both menus. As a result, I see my `searchview`-icon everywhere.
Can you please explain me, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `override` `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in all your **fragments** and **call** `super.onCreateOptionsMenu()` before anything else. **Alternatively**, use `menu.clear()` in those other fragments.